# Como armazenar o erro que o CI_Exception fornece

Tags: php, codeigniter, exceção

Olá, gostaria de capturar os erros PHP no codeigniter e armazenar no banco, ou ao menos exibir de uma forma mais suave ao usuário, no arquivo error_php.php são exibidos todos detalhes que preciso, até a linha do código onde o erro ocorreu, mas eu gostaria de conseguir essas informações no controller para poder armazenar.

```
<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>

<p>Severity: <?php echo $severity; ?></p>
<p>Message:  <?php echo $message; ?></p>
<p>Filename: <?php echo $filepath; ?></p>
<p>Line Number: <?php echo $line; ?></p>
```

Tentei com Try catch mas não funcionou, tentei jogar para o flashdata e depois usar, mas não é correto e mesmo assim não funcionou também.

Comment: Como vc tentou capturar a exception? em ambiente de produção essa msg gigante some (precisa configurar isso).

Comment: Oi, então tentei sim, mas na verdade não quero que suma não, quero conseguir armazenar o erro no banco de dados. ou pelo menos trabalhar ele de uma forma mais amigável. parece que quando é exception até é possível, ai ele redireciona para a view erro_exception, mas nesse caso ele manda para erro_php, acho que não tem uma exception pra esses erros (eu acho)

Answer (score 0):

É possível fazer o que você deseja, mas isto inclui alterar o core do CodeIgniter. É que o CodeIgniter define um gerenciamento personalizado de erros do PHP quando chama a função abaixo no arquivo `/system/core/CodeIgniter.php`:

```
set_error_handler('_error_handler');
```

E o tratamento das exceções passa para a função `_error_handler( )` no arquivo `/system/core/Commom.php`. Perceba que é nesta função o escopo das variáveis que você deseja utilizar:

```
function _error_handler($severity, $message, $filepath, $line) {
    $is_error = (((E_ERROR | E_COMPILE_ERROR | E_CORE_ERROR | E_USER_ERROR) & $severity) === $severity);

    if ($is_error)
        set_status_header(500);

    if (($severity & error_reporting()) !== $severity)
        return;

    $_error =& load_class('Exceptions', 'core');
    $_error->log_exception($severity, $message, $filepath, $line);

    if (str_ireplace(array('off', 'none', 'no', 'false', 'null'), '', ini_get('display_errors')))
        // AQUI ESTÃO AS VARIÁVEIS PRONTAS QUE VOCÊ DESEJA
        // O CODEIGNITER ESTÁ PRONTO PARA CHAMAR A VIEW

        // INSIRA DADOS NO BANCO AQUI, DE ACORDO COM USUÁRIO LOGADO, EXCEÇÃO, ETC...
        // $severity, $message, $filepath, $line !!!            

        $_error->show_php_error($severity, $message, $filepath, $line);

    if ($is_error)
        exit(1); // EXIT_ERROR
}
```